# Unit tests fail when run all at once but pass when I run individually

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito

Hi my unit tests in my Android project pass when I run them individually, but some of them fail when I run them all at once.

after looking online I have added the bellow code to my test fine but still they fail

@get:Rule
val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

MainActivityViewModelTest

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainActivityViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    @Mock
    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository
    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    @Test
    fun getCreditReport() {
        runBlocking {
            mainActivityViewModel.getCreditReport()
            verify(dataRepository).getCreditReport()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun getCreditReportWithStatusSuccess() {
        runBlocking {
        whenever(dataRepository.getCreditReport()).thenReturn(CreditReportResponse(null, CreditReportResponse.Status.SUCCESS))
            mainActivityViewModel.getCreditReport()
            verify(dataRepository).getCreditReport()
            val response = dataRepository.getCreditReport()
            Assert.assertEquals(CreditReportResponse.Status.SUCCESS, response.status)
        }
    }


    @Test
    fun getCreditReportWithStatusFailure() {
        runBlocking {
            whenever(dataRepository.getCreditReport()).thenReturn(CreditReportResponse(null, CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE))
            mainActivityViewModel.getCreditReport()
            verify(dataRepository).getCreditReport()
            val response = dataRepository.getCreditReport()
            Assert.assertEquals(CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE, response.status)
        }
    }
```

MainActivityViewModel

```
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataRepository: DataRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var creditReportLiveData: MutableLiveData<CreditReport>
    var serverErrorLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean>

    init {
        creditReportLiveData = MutableLiveData()
        serverErrorLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun getCreditReportObserver(): MutableLiveData<CreditReport> {
        return creditReportLiveData
    }

    fun getServerErrorLiveDataObserver(): MutableLiveData<Boolean> {
        return serverErrorLiveData
    }

    fun getCreditReport() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response = dataRepository.getCreditReport()

            when(response.status) {
                CreditReportResponse.Status.SUCCESS -> creditReportLiveData.postValue(response.creditReport)
                CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE -> serverErrorLiveData.postValue(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.8.47'
def mockitoKotlinLibrary = "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0"
androidTestImplementation mockitoKotlinLibrary
testImplementation mockitoKotlinLibrary
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
```

Can you suggest what I am doing wrong here please

Thanks
R

Comment: @MarkKeen thank you for coming back, I did try what you said and it still gives me the same errors. I tried doing assertions after runBlocking like this

Comment: @Test
    fun getCreditReportWithStatusFailure() {
        val response: CreditReportResponse
        runBlocking {
            whenever(dataRepository.getCreditReport()).thenReturn(CreditReportResponse(null, CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE))
            mainActivityViewModel.getCreditReport()
            verify(dataRepository).getCreditReport()
            response = dataRepository.getCreditReport()
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(CreditReportResponse.Status.FAILURE, response.status)
    }

Comment: Can you update your question with the console output please? It would help to see why the tests are failing. At a first guess it looks like your tests are set to run concurrently. The production code is equipped to handle that, but your test code isn't. When you use `Mockito.verify(...)` it finds the method is called more than once (because the tests run concurrently). I generally recommend against `Mockito.verify(...)` because it makes tests too inflexible. If you must have it, try `Mockito.verify(<obj>, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).<method>()`. But this might have false positives.